# Fragment shader normal artifacts appearing on specific GPU

Tags: three.js, shader, webgl, fragment-shader, normals

I am calculating normals from an `RGB` encoded height map:

[image]

`float unpackFactor = vec3(256.0 * 255.0, 255.0, 255.0 / 256.0);`

`float unpackOffset = -32768.0;`

Therefore I edited the phong shader built-in `dHdxy_fwd()` function:

```
vec2 dHdxy_fwd() {
    float texelSize = 1.0 / 256.0;
    vec2 dSTdx = vec2(texelSize, .0);
    vec2 dSTdy = vec2(.0, texelSize);

    float Hll = bumpScale * dot(texture2D(displacementMap, vUv).rgb, unpackFactors) + unpackOffset;
    float dBx = bumpScale * dot(texture2D(displacementMap, vUv + dSTdx).rgb, unpackFactors) + unpackOffset - Hll;
    float dBy = bumpScale * dot(texture2D(displacementMap, vUv + dSTdy).rgb, unpackFactors) + unpackOffset - Hll;

    return vec2(dBx, dBy);
}
```

The decoding of the height, unfortunately, causes *artifacts around the green channel* of the texture – happening on **iPhone 7, iPhone XS** and the **Radeon 455 dedicated GPU** of my Mac:

[image]

Those artifacts look like this:

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

On the **Intel HD Graphics 530** (integrated GPU), however, there are *no such artifacts visible* – it looks perfect just as it should (ignore the tile seams for):

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

Why are artifacts appearing on some (most of the tested) GPUs? Any idea how to get rid of them? Seems like some numerical instability, but I fumbled around with texture precision, compressing the total height value, etc. with no luck yet.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but the only time I've heard of iPhones behaving differently than other GPUs is with texture precision, since iPhones can only handle HalfFloatType. Maybe this could help? https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gpgpucomputationrenderer/3233/2?u=marquizzo

Comment: can you post a **minimal** repo [in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? Then maybe it would be possible to help. As it is it seems like you're basically asking us to write our own repo from your tiny GLSL function of code which when we're done it may or may not show the issue

Comment: Ok, setting `texture.type = THREE.FloatType` fixes the artifacts – however, as @Marquizzo said, iPhones don't support this. Now I need to find a way to compensate this drawback. Thanks for the link, I'm still trying to dig into this.

Comment: @GeorgMolzer Did you read the code sample in the link I posted? Use HalfFloat on devices that don't support Float.

Comment: @Marquizzo Yes, I did, thank you! However, HalfFloatType still results in artifacts. Only when using FloatType, they're gone. I assume that the linear filtering of the RGB height map introduces numerical instabilities so fine that they can only be fixed with 32 bit floats.